# getting duplicates after using distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, one is mapping tale and I am using distinct keyword even though getting duplicate values

```
SELECT
  mer.store_name,      mpr.`merchant_code` ,    mpr.`terminal_num` ,
  mpr.`rec_fmt` ,      mpr.`bat_nbr` ,          mpr.`Card_Type` ,
  mpr.`card_num` ,     mpr.`transaction_date` , mpr.`settle_date` ,
  mpr.`approval_code`, mpr.`intnl_amt` ,        mpr.`domestic_amt` ,
  mpr.`transid` ,      mpr.`upvalue` ,          mpr.`merchant_trackid` ,
  mpr.`MSF` ,          mpr.`service_tax` ,      mpr.`edu_cess` ,
  mpr.`net_amount` ,   mpr.`debit_credit_type`, mpr.`UDF1` ,
  mpr.`UDF2` ,         mpr.`UDF3` ,             mpr.`UDF4` ,
  mpr.`UDF5` ,         mpr.`seq_num` ,          mpr.`arn_no`
FROM
  `mpr_reports` mpr, merchantreports mer, storename_tid sid
WHERE (
  mer.Store_Name = sid.Store_Name
  AND sid.terminal_num = mpr.terminal_num
  AND mpr.`rec_fmt` = 'cvd'
  OR mpr.`rec_fmt` = 'bat'
)
```

Comment: Where do you use the `DISTINCT` keyword?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is hidden :) people have to guess the column needs `DISTINCT `

Comment: OK. I take a guess: mpr.`seq_num` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider amending the published query to something like this...

```
SELECT mer.store_name
     , mpr.merchant_code 
     , mpr.terminal_num 
     , mpr.rec_fmt 
     , mpr.bat_nbr 
     , mpr.Card_Type 
     , mpr.card_num 
     , mpr.transaction_date 
     , mpr.settle_date 
     , mpr.approval_code 
     , mpr.intnl_amt 
     , mpr.domestic_amt 
     , mpr.transid 
     , mpr.upvalue 
     , mpr.merchant_trackid 
     , mpr.MSF 
     , mpr.service_tax 
     , mpr.edu_cess 
     , mpr.net_amount 
     , mpr.debit_credit_type 
     , mpr.UDF1 
     , mpr.UDF2 
     , mpr.UDF3 
     , mpr.UDF4 
     , mpr.UDF5 
     , mpr.seq_num 
     , mpr.arn_no
  FROM mpr_reports mpr
  JOIN storename_tid sid
    ON sid.terminal_num = mpr.terminal_num
  JOIN merchantreports mer
    ON mer.Store_Name = sid.Store_Name
 WHERE mpr.rec_fmt IN ('cvd','bat')
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.But query is not executing

Comment: I don't know what 'not executing' means.

Comment: @Strawberry, you are using table "sid" on line 30, but you define it at line 31 (`... JOIN storename_tid sid`)

Comment: So you see how useful it is to write queries out properly :-)

Answer (score 0):

About SQL joins, you may have some fun [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)...
It's the kind of thing we learn once, to use during our entire life.

About your specific query, test this first example,

```
SELECT
  mer.store_name,
  mpr.`merchant_code`,
  mpr.`terminal_num`,
  mpr.`rec_fmt`,
  mpr.`bat_nbr`,
  mpr.`Card_Type`,
  mpr.`card_num`,
  mpr.`transaction_date`,
  mpr.`settle_date`,
  mpr.`approval_code`,
  mpr.`intnl_amt`,
  mpr.`domestic_amt`,
  mpr.`transid`,
  mpr.`upvalue`,
  mpr.`merchant_trackid`,
  mpr.`MSF`,
  mpr.`service_tax`,
  mpr.`edu_cess`,
  mpr.`net_amount`,
  mpr.`debit_credit_type`,
  mpr.`UDF1`,
  mpr.`UDF2`,
  mpr.`UDF3`,
  mpr.`UDF4`,
  mpr.`UDF5`,
  mpr.`seq_num`,
  mpr.`arn_no`
FROM merchantreports mer
INNER JOIN storename_tid sid ON (sid.Store_Name = mer.Store_Name)
INNER JOIN `mpr_reports` mpr ON (sid.terminal_num = mpr.terminal_num)
WHERE mpr.rec_fmt IN ('cvd','bat');
```

Just a humble advice, consider using foreign keys to join your tables. Indexing columns "Store_Name" and "terminal_num" is also an option, but it'll be rather more efficient to follow what's written in the [scriptures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-innodb-tables.html) (see sec. 5.4.5).

Comment: Thanks Query Working But too many Duplicates.Thanks for your interest

Comment: @vinodJ, can you update your question with your create statements? Only tables merchantreports, mpr_reports & storename_tid

Comment: I forget to advice you that AND operators have higher precedence than OR ones; you should put `mpr.rec_fmt = 'cvd' OR mpr.rec_fmt = 'bat'` in parentheses